# How to automatically include a copy of resource files when compiling without embedding them?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have the following XAML code:

```
<dxm:MapPolygon EnableHighlighting="False">
<dxm:MapPolygon.StrokeStyle>
    <dxm:StrokeStyle Thickness="0"/>
</dxm:MapPolygon.StrokeStyle>
<dxm:MapPolygon.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ShapeFiles\Piran\B010262.tif"/>
</dxm:MapPolygon.Fill>
<dxm:MapPolygon.Points>
    <dxm:GeoPoint Latitude="45.4922488128447995" Longitude="13.6751748869624681" />
    <dxm:GeoPoint Latitude="45.4922488128447995" Longitude="13.7045866089215824" />
    <dxm:GeoPoint Latitude="45.5195646122025437" Longitude="13.7045866089215824" />
    <dxm:GeoPoint Latitude="45.5195646122025437" Longitude="13.6751748869624681" />
</dxm:MapPolygon.Points>
</dxm:MapPolygon>
```

This used to generate a **ShapeFiles/Piran/B010262.tif** folder next to the .exe file in the release folder, but now I get `system.windows.baml2006.typeconvertermarkupextension` exception instead.

If I add the files as a resource, they get embedded into the .exe file and I end up with a 600MB exe, which I do not want, because I want the users to be able to update the .tif files even without source code.

If I include the full path, for example `ImageSource="c:\ShapeFiles\Piran\B010262.tif"/>`, the program will compile just fine, but then I am bound to that location.

How do I add files as a resource without embedding them into an exe file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the files that you want to exclude from embedding.
2. Properties > Build Action: Content
3. Properties > Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

Also, be sure to delete the **obj\Release** directory before compiling, otherwise the files might still get embedded into the exe.

Source: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-application-resource-content-and-data-files?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:~:text=Resource%20Files%3A%20Data%20files%20that,with%20an%20executable%20WPF%20assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-application-resource-content-and-data-files?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:%7E:text=Resource%20Files%3A%20Data%20files%20that,with%20an%20executable%20WPF%20assembly)